# Using Flask is it possible to use 'get' to return the entire table or the ID when clicked?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm using pandas to_html to create a table. I can edit and manipulate the string easily so if it's necessary to change every row that's not a problem at all.

Is it possible using flask to use the get method to return the entire row or the ID to my script?

Alternatively if easier when the row is clicked route to another page and parse the ID or the entire row?

I've been messing around for a while and just can't seem to find a method of doing this.

It's fairly important that I use 'get' rather than post.

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td><a href={{ url_for('main' }}>James</a></td>
      <td><a href={{ url_for('main' }}>8532</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td><a href={{ url_for('main' }}>Maximus</a></td>
      <td><a href={{ url_for('main' }}>1632</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't paste all my code here, it wouldn't be very helpful either as this is more of a general question on how I'd tackle this problem.

In my HTML I am using the below code to display it.

```
        {% for table in TABLES %}
        {{TITLES[loop.index]}}
        {{ table|safe }}
        {% endfor %}
```

Currently when I run this code in my Flask I go into my 'get' if statement although the URL goes to IP/%7B%7B

Comment: Using a get doesn't look like it's the issue here. [Routing](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) seems to be.

Comment: @Er... Hey Er, It's less of the get being an issue but the question is more how would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your issue is two-folds

1. Make the routes to get the resources you need (here it appears to be names, or people)
2. Link to these routes in your table, by way of `url_for()`

Luckily you seem to already have an ID, which will serve for your resources.

So, first define your routes:

```
@app.route('/person/<int: id>') # your ids seem to be integers
def person_read(id):
    # show whatever data you get on that person
    # use a template if you like
    person_data = get_person_data()
    return person_data
```

Then you need to get a link to that route to put in your table, and build a link through `url_for()`. I'm guessing that you're iterating over your dataframe to build your table, and that inside said dataframe there is a `person_id` value. So, one of your table's cell should have something like that:

`<td><a href={{ url_for('person', person_id) }}>{{ person_id }}</a></td>`

If this sounds like gibberish to you, you probably need to get through the [flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/)